# Ignored Tags - Don't Disappear?

Tags: feature-request, tagging

When I ignore a tag on database administrators stack exchange, it doesn't have the same effect as in other stack exchange sites (like stack overflow).  Instead of just hiding the ignored tags' posts, it just dims them.

Is this a user-configurable option?  Or completely out of my control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a user-configurable option!

[Check out the rarely-used Prefs page in your profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/2241/surfer513?tab=prefs) (`https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/surfer513?tab=prefs`) - see that little checkbox labelled "hide ignored tags"? Check it.